# SFTP to EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: security, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

So i've setup a windows instance, but can't seem to FTP into it.  After much research, i've discovered SFTP is the way forward.

I've setup my security group, adding the following rule:
 SSH  tcp  22  22  0.0.0.0/0

Using the public DNS name supplied in the console, i try to SFTP in using Filezilla & Cyberduck, but they just time out.

I know the next step is sorting out the key pairs, but i doubt that'll do me any good if my server isn't even accepting connections.

Any idea what i've missed?

EDIT:
Looking at the Filezilla logs, its looks like the server isn't responding to the connection requests...

```
12:51:29    Status: Connecting to ec2-122-248-248-178.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com...
12:51:29    Response:   fzSftp started
12:51:29    Command:    keyfile "D:\Users\berling\Lacie Fuj Sync\Freelancing\AWS_Public_Key.ppk"
12:51:29    Command:    open "greg@ec2-122-248-248-178.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" 22
12:51:49    Error:  Connection timed out
12:51:49    Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Do i need to install an SFTP/SSH server on the server? I was under the impression it was already setup for Amazon servers for some reason... am i wrong about that?

Comment: Seems you have configured ppk properly, but not sure about username and other parameters, I'm following steps mentioned in this video and successfully connected using filezilla: http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 2):

The rule you have set up - SSH tcp 22 22 0.0.0.0/0 - where is that? Your firewall, or at the EC2 end? And why 0.0.0.0? I would recommend using real IP addresses.

Check why the connection is timing out - is SFTP getting past your firewall? Is it getting blocked at the EC2 end - firewall or network logs will be your friend here.

Have you confirmed it is timing out before starting the handshake? Check SSH logs.

Do you have an SFTP server running and configured correctly? Some require all configs to be set before they are happy - your comment that you haven't yet sorted key pairs makes me wonder if this one only accepts certificate auth.

Check those and see how you do.

Comment: hey Rory,

Thanks for the info... i setup with 0.0.0.0 as i ftp from dynamic IPs.. i'll lock it down to springloops IP once its all working and i can deploy code from there every time.  That rule is on the EC2 end, in the security groups assigned to the VM.  I dont have a local firewall, so dont think the issue is local.

I'll check all logs I can find and see if they give me any clues.

Comment: As for setting up SFTP on the server, i was under the impression that the Amazon AMIs had SFTP ready to go... or am i wrong about that?  If i am, any recommendations on a solid and free/cheap SFTP server i can install?

Comment: If your using Linux AMI (Amazon AMI or Ubuntu) you can directly sftp since it's running SSH server. But if you're running Windows instance, I think you need to install SSH/SFTP server first.

Comment: I reckon you're probably right Rodney.  I think i'll just open up port 21 and use FTP for now.. i'm still just evaluating EC2, dont want to waste too much time on unnecessary activities.

Comment: @Jeeby have you been able to resolve the issue? I have the same one now :/

Comment: @OndrejTokar Nope I never resolved it. I was just trialling EC2, and gave up soon after I hit this roadblock.

Comment: @Jeeby, thank you for your answer. That is a shame. Though I think to make it work you need to install a Git, setup SSH keys, upload the public one onto AWS and then do some configuration in registry and then it will work. (All that is in AWS tutorial...) I expected it would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Install [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) on your EC2 instance.  It provides RDP, SFTP, Console access - all over port 22.

Install [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) on your client.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this particular package, but Cygwin, and Services for Unix provide OpenSSH version.
Copssh claims to install openssh, and allow migration/configuration of users:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sereds/files/Copssh/4.0.4/